# Which files I have to push in GitHub from New Android Project?

Tags: android

I have just sync my GitHub with Android Studio and I create a new project. I want to push it in my git repository. Last time when I did this with my previous android project, I saw that some foldres like .idea, gradle and other files out of the app folder are never updated again. They are staying like the first commit. So tell me - which folders I have to upload for full application without any missing recourse and others? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Typical gitignore file for an android project :

```
#built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db

# OSX files
.DS_Store

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Android Studio
.idea
#.idea/workspace.xml - remove # and delete .idea if it better suit your needs.
.gradle
build/
```

Comment: Don't forget .iml files. If If you're sharing the project with other users or developing on multiple machines, these should not be in git.

Answer (score 2):

You can find sample .gitignore files in GitHub's [gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) repository. The one for [Android](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) is:

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log
```

You can also add your IDE related files and directories to this .gitignore file. For example for Android Studio:

```
# Android Studio
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/
```